# Another adjective rather than good which is used to describe sleeping quality

Tags: synonyms, register

I am trying to find an adjective to describe sleeping quality other than good, which is used to describe **sleeping quality,** the word will be used in biology report writing.

so the following words cannot be used

***amazing, fantastic, awesome, wonderful, and great.***

*Thank you for your help.*

Comment: It is human sleep?

Comment: Sleeping soundly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we speak of sleep *disturbances*, "good" or "proper" sleep could be called **undisturbed sleep**. [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1978383/) uses the phrase "undisturbed sleep" several times, including "undisturbed all-night sleep".

It also refers to "sleep fragmentation", so you could also use **unfragmented sleep**.

Answer (score 1):

***[Deep](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deep)*** is often used to convey the idea of a good sleep:

> - very strongly felt or experienced and usually lasting a long time:
>
>   - *Their son has been a deep disappointment to them.
>       We're in deep trouble.
>       **She fell into a deep sleep.***

Cambridge Dictionary

The expression [deep sleep](https://www.google.it/search?q=deep%20sleep%20matress&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=deep%20sleep%20matress&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6446j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) is often used in relation to mattresses that are supposed to be very confortable.

Comment: The term *deep sleep* is used by doctors to describe non-REM sleep (when we do not dream). All mammals experience deep sleep as part of the normal sleep cycle. Perhaps *sound sleep* would be better since there are no medical connotations as far as I know?

Comment: *Undisturbed sleep* might be appropriate when discussing animals. All animals sleep well if they are left undisturbed. After all, they don't lie awake at night worrying about the mortgage.

Comment: @MickSharpe - please see secon the link I posted in my answer.